# Intercommunication with two dlls but without known each other

Tags: c#, dll

I need a struct as function parameter that is not known in the given dlls.

I want to process two different types. The types are generated as two different dlls. I instanciate many of those types via Xml-Serialization. A third party application load the dlls and start to make instances from the given xml files. Then i iterate over the instances and call a function from the dll to do something like an export. On processing i get global data i want to share to the next instance. The problem on this is, they dont know about the global data. They got only a function parameter typeof(object). If i implement the same struct in each of those dlls i cant cast it into the struct, because dll A and dll B are different. So what can i do... ?

```
//Third party application
object globalData = null; //Type is not known in this application

//serialisation here...
I_SVExternalFruitExport[] instances = serialisation(....);

foreach(I_SVExternalFruitExport sv in instances)
{
    globalData = sv.ProcessMyType(globalData, sv);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
// one DLL AppleExport implements I_SVExternalFruitExport
using Apple.dll

struct s_mytype // s_mytype  is known in this dll
{
    List<string> lines;
    ...
}
local_sv;
public object ProcessMyType(object s_TypeStruct, object sv)
{
     local_sv = (Apple)sv;
    if(globalData != null) globalData = new s_mytype();
    else globalData = (s_mytype)s_TypeData;
    //Do Stuff
    return globalData;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------
// second DLL OrangeExport  implements I_SVExternalFruitExport 
using Orange.dll

struct s_mytype    //s_mytype  is known in this dll
{
    List<string> lines;
    ...
}
Orange local_sv;   // Orange is known because of using Orange.dll

public object ProcessMyType(object s_TypeStruct, object sv)
{
    local_sv = (Orange)sv;
    if(globalData != null) globalData = new s_mytype();
    else globalData = (s_mytype)s_TypeData; //This cast says... s_TypeData is not s_mytype because of two dlls A and B but i know they have the same structure.
    //Do Stuff
    return globalData;
}
```

I need a struct that is known in my dlls but not in the third party application, because i want to regenerate my dlls, maybe with some more information in the struct. I dont want to update my third party application every time i change my dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got an answer:
I will make my struct s_mytype{} also serializeable:

```
[Serializable]
public struct s_mytype
{
    public List<string> lines;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Lines", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string[] Lines 
    { 
       get { return lines.ToArray(); } 
       set { lines.AddRange(value); } 
    }
}
```

My function "ProcessMyType()" now have to return a string with xml data:

```
public string ProcessMyType(object s_TypeStruct, object sv)
```

Now the only thing is, that every instance of an "Apple" or "Orange" have to deserilize the xml first, and it get bigger and bigger with each instance.
My Generator give the garantee that in every dll is the same struct s_mytype.

Maybe this post make the problem more clear. If there is a easier way or a way with less overload like deserialize, please let me know.